# Seagate external HDD not mounting

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have an old(ish) 3tb Seagate HDD that has a lot of material on it and I wish to transfer it to my snazzy new external HDD. I'm having no end of problems doing so.
When I first booted my laptop with the HDD plugged in it appeared in Dolphin but wouldn't mount it. It gave the error:

> An error occurred while accessing 'Seagate Expansion Drive', the
>   system responded: An unspecified error has occurred: Did not receive a
>   reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a
>   reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply
>   timeout expired, or the network connection was broken

So I used testdisk to rewrite the file system and I could access it via Dolphin. I started copying data across and after about 20 minutes it crapped out and now it doesn't appear in Dolphin at all. It is still appearing in lsusb

```
andy@rsehole:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b52d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b008 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 248a:8366  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bc2:3320 Seagate RSS LLC SRD00F2 [Expansion Desktop Drive]
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It also doesn't appear with sudo fdisk -l

When I connect it dmesg gives:

```
[  791.085934] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=248a, idProduct=8366, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  791.085943] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  791.085947] usb 3-2: Product: 2.4G Mouse
[  791.085951] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Telink
[  791.116913] input: Telink 2.4G Mouse Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:248A:8366.0002/input/input16
[  791.176601] input: Telink 2.4G Mouse Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:248A:8366.0002/input/input17
[  791.176886] input: Telink 2.4G Mouse System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:248A:8366.0002/input/input18
[  791.177168] hid-generic 0003:248A:8366.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Telink 2.4G Mouse] on usb-0000:00:10.0-2/input0
[  798.403575] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  798.558461] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=3320, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  798.558499] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  798.558504] usb 1-1.1: Product: Expansion Desk
[  798.558508] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  798.558511] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[  798.560804] scsi host3: uas
[  798.562471] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion Desk   0711 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  798.564513] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  798.565203] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[  799.575484] ...........ready
[  809.816599] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 732566645 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.73 TiB)
```

So it is seeing the thing but I have no idea what to do next. I had a look with gparted but it isn't showing up there either.

I'm at a complete loss. I really don't want to lose this data. Yeah, I know that no one wants to lose data but it's something like 10 year's worth of photos and the like.
Any help will be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Later I rebooted with the device plugged in and ran dmesg again. It now gives:

```
[  168.898401] xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: bad transfer trb length 16777210 in event trb
[  168.914306] scsi host3: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  175.026271] xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  180.402145] xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  180.610068] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 6, error -62
[  186.034167] xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  191.414216] xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  191.621999] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 6, error -62
[  197.042023] xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  202.418072] xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  202.625980] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 6, error -62
[  208.050046] xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  213.426088] xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  213.633866] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 6, error -62
[  213.690143] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

Device 6 being my external HDD.
I really am flummoxed.

Comment: Should have mentioned, I'm using Kubuntu 19.04

Comment: External 3T USB drives don't get enough power from the USB port. You need to either use an AC adapter on the external drive case, or use a POWERED USB hub. Using testdisk probably didn't help the situation either.

Comment: It is running on AC.

Comment: See if you can get a screenshot of the SMART Data using the `Disks` app. Edit that into your question. Also try running the SMART Tests.

Comment: I'll do that in the morning.

Comment: Start comments to me with @heynnema, or I'll surely miss them.

Comment: I mean, I'll do that in the morning and do you know if the Disks utility is available in KDE or if there's an equivalent? Thanks. :)

Comment: Oh, that's right... you're on kubuntu. I think the equivalent app is `KDE something`. You might be able to use smartmontools.

Comment: @heynema either KDEsomething of Ksomething. XD

Comment: I don't know the exact name... I don't use kubuntu... you'll have to search/research that. If needed, I think that you can install `Disks` on kubuntu.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319019/is-there-a-kde-tool-for-mounting-disk-images-like-gnome-disks. See the accepted answer. (sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility)

Comment: @heynema Good morning! I've tried running Disks and it also doesn't see the drive. Though the HDD is still spinning up and is making the occasional noise as though something is happening in there.

Comment: Also, it isn't showing up in lsusb. There's just a blank entry....

Comment: You could have a bad 3T HDD, or the enclosure's internal USB -> Sata interface board could be bad, or the AC power supply could be bad. Do you have access to a desktop machine? If so, remove the HDD from its enclosure, and connect it to an extra SATA port on the desktop machine, and retest the drive that way.

Comment: @heynnema That's next on my list. I'm going to shuck the drive and see if I can borrow a caddy from a friend. Rather than opening up my ancient clockwork desktop.
I'm not concerned about losing the HDD but I just want to be able to either get the data off or at least make an image with ddrescue. Or anything really.
Once I've had a go at plugging it in via SATA I'll come back and say how it went. Unfortunately I work away from home so it will next weekend before I have the time.
Thanks for helping me out. :)